# Domain owner uses my IP without permission

Tags: dns, ip-address

as I discovered recently a lot of domains of a certain organisation all have their A-Record set to the IP of a server that I own. The server currently does only host security auditing tools and does not contain a website. However I might want to host something with this IP in the future and do not want to be associated with the domain-owner at all. I already looked up the whois information and tried to contact the organization. I did not receive any reply. Is there anything I can do to get the domain owner to no longer use my IP?

**EDIT:**

I ended up deleting and re-creating the virtual-server which gave me a new IP. Not the best soltuion since someone else will now "pull this IP out of the hat" when setting up his/her v-server.

Comment: The fact that this domain has an `A` record pointing to your IP address is presumably a mistake, or is it an historical hangover and has just not been updated? What is the response from your server when requesting this domain? Presumably "not much" since you aren't hosting a website?

Comment: Set up a redirect to pornhub or some other site you think they would find objectionable for requests coming from that domain. Then, depending on the nature of their organisation, contact the appropriate channels about it and complain that their site is providing them with inappropriate content.

Comment: @TZHX I like the way you think! I would not complain at all. I would just watch and wait for the A records to change. They will. It is possible that w3d is correct. If it is possible, be persistent. You can also send a demand letter (legal) to ensure that they: one, get the message; and two, you have covered your bases just in case something comes down the line and you want to take some kind of action. There may be other actions to take less dramatic. Just make sure you do not harm your own IP addresses reputation in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I don't think the configuration is a mistake on their part. The Organisation in question hosts a website for ordering food online and seem to have bought a ton (13+) Domains with food related names just to prevent others from having them without planing to use them in any way. Since I use this IP for about a year now I don't think it is a historical hangover either. My Server with this IP has been offline for several months now. I only enable it when I set up a new Server to perform vulnaribility scans on it.

Comment: I think I'll take closetnoc's advice and write an official letter. What originally brought this whole thing to my attention was that my server provider informed me that they received a complaint from a swiz governmental institution about a website that I allegedly own which contains maleware. Since my Server was onffline for a long time and is currently not running either I started to look into it and discovered the invalid A-Records. I would assume that the Domain in question previously linked to another IP someone complaint about ...

Comment: ... Instead of using the Domain Information it seems that the swiz government institution performed a reverse IP Lookup sometime later which pointed to my server. At this point the informed the BSI (which is a german government institution) which in turn informed my Server provider who then warned me that I would violate their terms of service. This whole thing really made me rub my head. I asked my Server provider how a Server that isn't even online nor has been for months could violate their terms of service but was told they just respond to complains without checking whether they are true-

Comment: Is it imperative that you continue using the same IP address? Is it possible that you could ask for a new one from your host, explaining the reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In life you can take on fights that are not worth the time no matter if you are right or wrong, change IPs and move on, use time in a positive manner forget the fights that that are not worth wasting your time on.

If you are gonna spend money on legal letters, be prepared to pay more money and spend time than you will ever hope to get back, roll with the punches be positive and move forward.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much that you can do effectively, besides what has already been mentioned. A legal letter could work, and so could redirecting the IP so something that they wouldn't want to be associated with.

You could also try looking at any traffic coming from their domain to see what they are trying to access, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

Not much you can do, as the DNS is not administered by you. Any record can point to any IP -- so I guess you're just out of luck :(

You can, of course, try to contact the domain owner and ask if they could change the record. You can spend as much time as you want on this, but if it's worth it... I'd say no.